# Jquery - How do I access the element that was clicked to run a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I am using jQuery . I have some code like below -

----HTML-----

```
<table> 
<tr>
<td class="cell" id="cell1" ></td>
<td class="cell" id="cell2"></td>
<td class="cell" id="cell3" ></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td class="cell" id="cell4"></td>
<td class="cell" id="cell5"></td>
<td class="cell" id="cell6"></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

---

---JS----

```
$(".cell").click(function() {

do_something();

}

function do_something(){

// I want to print the id of the cell that was clicked here . 

}
```

How do I access the element that caused the function to be run ? For eg in the above code , I want to access the id of the cell that was clicked from inside the function do_Something()

Comment: he wants to display id not value, so try this: $(this).attr('id')

Comment: `this.id` is much better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".cell").click(function() {
    do_something(this); // this is the clicked element
});
function do_something(element){
    console.log(element.id); // open the console to see the result
}
```

Of course it would be simpler to simply call it directly :

```
$(".cell").click(do_something);  
function do_something(){
    console.log(this.id); // open the console to see the result
}
```

or

```
$(".cell").click(function(){
    console.log(this.id); // open the console to see the result
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! I cant put the function inside  because I need to do this at many places in the code - so unnecessary repetition of code.